# How to get the line no while extracting text from pdf file using Pdfbox in java?

Tags: java, itext, pdfbox, apache-tika

Is there an any way to get the line no along with the text i'm extracting using pdfbox?

I got no of pages using .getNumberOfPages() method.
and I'm iterating over pages to extract text page by page using .getText() method.
and I'm storing extracted text in String variable.

Just Curious, why there isn't any method for line number in both apache pdfbox and itext library?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "line number" in PDFs, only coordinates. You can put text wherever you want, in whatever rotation you want.